# A C++ version of the %in% operator in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

Is there any function in C++ equivalent to `%in%` operator in R? Consider the command below in R:

```
which(y %in% x)
```

I tried to find something equivalent in C++ (specifically in Armadillo) and I couldn't find anything. I then wrote my own function which is very slow compared to the R command above.

Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec myInOperator(arma::vec myBigVec, arma::vec mySmallVec ){
 arma::uvec rslt = find(myBigVec == mySmallVec[0]);
 for (int i = 1; i < mySmallVec.size(); i++){
   arma::uvec rslt_tmp = find(myBigVec == mySmallVec[i]);
   rslt = arma::unique(join_cols( rslt, rslt_tmp ));
 }
 return rslt;
}
```

Now after sourcing in the code above, we have:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 1:10
res <- benchmark(myInOperator(y, x), which(y %in% x), columns = c("test",
      "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"), 
       order = "relative")
```

And here are the results:

```
                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
 2    which(y %in% x)          100   0.001        1     0.001        0
 1 myInOperator(y, x)          100   0.002        2     0.001        0
```

Could anyone guide me either on finding a C++ code corresponding to which(y %in% x) or on making my code more efficient? The elapsed time is already very small for both functions. I guess what I meant by efficiency is more from programming perspective and on whether the way I thought about the problem and the commands I used are efficient.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: It will be hard to beat `which(y %in% x)`, since `%in%` (calling `match`) and `which` are already `.Internal` functions, and hence implemented in C and likely optimized. It is possible that one could improve performance by avoiding the temporary logical vector generated by `%in%` though.

Comment: It would probably help a little if you pass stuff by reference instead of making copies, `(const arma::vec & myBigVec, const arma::vec & mySmallVec )`

Comment: I dont't know enough about RCpp (and nothing of Armidillo) so I can't answer the question.  However, if I were doing this in C++, I would look to `std::set_intersection`.

Comment: @KevinUshey, would you happen to know a way to use %in% in C++ by using Rcpp? Is there a way to call which and %in%. While I can easily call other R functions, I was not successful to use which and I have no idea how to use %in%. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For a question like this (how to duplicate/imitate feature X of language Y in language Z) it's *extremely* helpful if you describe exactly what the feature does--or at least the subset of its capabilities you care about.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `y %in% x` returns a logical vector the same length as `y`, value `TRUE` if the element of `y` is in `x`, else `FALSE`.  `which` returns the numeric indices (1-based) of the `TRUE` values in a vector.

Comment: @matthewlundberg what is a 'logical vector'?  How is it distinct from a `std::vector`? Is it lazy?  Do you want `%in%` and `which`, or just `which(a %in% b)`?

Comment: @Yakk The question includes the R tag.  These of course are constructs of R.  A "logical vector" in R only relates to a `std::vector` when RCpp is involved.  Perhaps this question should not have the C++ tag applied, as R and RCpp are a bit different.  But the message here is, if a question has tags about a language with which you are unfamiliar, you might refrain from answering or commenting.  That's what I do with answers with tags in languages that I do not know.

Comment: @matthewlundberg except the OP wants C++ code: I can produce that code if the specs are clear.  The set of people competent at two random languages is going to be much smaller: if, as the below answer (now deleted) implies, a pure C++ algorithm on `std::vector<int>` suffices, the `R` tag becomes redundant!

Comment: @Yakk But it's not pure!  It relies on RCpp and it must be callable from the R interpreter.  If you can do that, great.  If not, well...

Comment: For the purposes of this question, a pure C++ solution could easily be made callable using `Rcpp`, but it would not necessarily be the fastest due to data copies forced in going from R containers to C++ containers. There are ways around this, but it is not the default behavior.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: We tend to spell it Rcpp (lower-case c) and have done since 2008.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I will mind that in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to @MatthewLundberg and @Yakk for catching my silly errors.

If what you really want is just faster matching, you should check out Simon Urbanek's [fastmatch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastmatch/index.html) package. However, `Rcpp` does in fact have a sugar `in` function which can be used here. `in` uses some of the ideas from the `fastmatch` package and incorporates them into `Rcpp`. I also compare @hadley's solution here.

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> sugar_in(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y) {
  LogicalVector ind = in(x, y);
  int n = ind.size();
  std::vector<int> output;
  output.reserve(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (ind[i]) output.push_back(i+1);
  }
  return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> which_in(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y) {
  int nx = x.size();
  std::unordered_set<int> z(y.begin(), y.end());
  std::vector<int> output;
  output.reserve(nx);
  for (int i=0; i < nx; ++i) {
    if (z.find( x[i] ) != z.end() ) {
      output.push_back(i+1);
    }
  }
  return output;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> which_in2(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y) {
  std::vector<int> y_sort(y.size());
  std::partial_sort_copy (y.begin(), y.end(), y_sort.begin(), y_sort.end());

  int nx = x.size();
  std::vector<int> out;

  for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator found =
      lower_bound(y_sort.begin(), y_sort.end(), x[i]);
    if (found != y_sort.end()) {
      out.push_back(i + 1);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
library(microbenchmark)
x <- sample(1:100)
y <- sample(1:10000, 1000)
identical( sugar_in(y, x), which(y %in% x) )
identical( which_in(y, x), which(y %in% x) )
identical( which_in2(y, x), which(y %in% x) )
microbenchmark(
  sugar_in(y, x),
  which_in(y, x),
  which_in2(y, x),
  which(y %in% x)
)
*/
```

Calling `sourceCpp` on this gives me, from the benchmark,

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr    min      lq  median      uq    max neval
  sugar_in(y, x)  7.590 10.0795 11.4825 14.3630 32.753   100
  which_in(y, x) 40.757 42.4460 43.4400 46.8240 63.690   100
 which_in2(y, x) 14.325 15.2365 16.7005 17.2620 30.580   100
 which(y %in% x) 17.070 21.6145 23.7070 29.0105 78.009   100
```

Comment: Must you copy the vectors when you call `which_in`?

Comment: The sort of lhs makes the return values order wrong.  Try using an unordered set copied from rhs, and transform lhs without duplicating it first?  Faster by a log factor too.  For extra credit produce the output lazily (mayhap using `boost`).  Oh and note that any iterable range is a valid lhs and rhs: dunno if R makes that useless.

Comment: What about Armadillo's `find()` as per [this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) ?

Comment: FWIW, Rcpp has an `in` sugar function. https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/unique.h#L77 Under the hood it will use something similar to what Kevin shows here.

Comment: You can do a bit better using a binary search. See my answer below.

Comment: Looks like Rcpp's sugar can still win the battle :)

Answer (score 9):

For this set of inputs we can eke out a little more performance by using an approach that technically has a higher algorithmic complexity (O(ln n) vs O(1) for each lookup) but has lower constants: a binary search.

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> which_in(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y) {
  int nx = x.size();
  std::unordered_set<int> z(y.begin(), y.end());
  std::vector<int> output;
  output.reserve(nx);
  for (int i=0; i < nx; ++i) {
    if (z.find( x[i] ) != z.end() ) {
      output.push_back(i+1);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> which_in2(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y) {
  std::vector<int> y_sort(y.size());
  std::partial_sort_copy (y.begin(), y.end(), y_sort.begin(), y_sort.end());

  int nx = x.size();
  std::vector<int> out;

  for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator found =
      lower_bound(y_sort.begin(), y_sort.end(), x[i]);
    if (found != y_sort.end()) {
      out.push_back(i + 1);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
library(microbenchmark)
x <- sample(1:100)
y <- sample(1:10000, 1000)
identical( which_in(y, x), which(y %in% x) )
identical( which_in2(y, x), which(y %in% x) )
microbenchmark(
  which_in(y, x),
  which_in2(y, x),
  which(y %in% x)
)
*/
```

On my computer that yields

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
  which_in(y, x) 39.3 41.0   42.7 44.0 81.5   100
 which_in2(y, x) 12.8 13.6   14.4 15.0 23.8   100
 which(y %in% x) 16.8 20.2   21.0 21.9 31.1   100
```

so about 30% better than base R.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `which_in2` has complexity O(n log n)?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg oops, I got confused. I meant O(1), referring to individual lookups.